# advance inner join get whole data data from another table as a array

Tags: mysql, laravel-7

Im working on laravel 7 and come acrros this issue.
I have one table of **customers** and other is **transactions** both are connectd with each other with foreign key primary key relation.
I have one customer and 4 transactions related to him in transactions table and i want those 4 transactions data in a single array format not a seperate row for each transaction record.

Here is my query

```
$customers =  DB::table('customers')
            ->join('transactions', 'customers.id', '=', 'transactions.custId')
            ->select('customers.*','transactions.*')
            ->get();
```

Any mysql expert please look into this.

want result like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItsWy.png)

Comment: Why do you have a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: i was trying but that didn't work. i have removed this.

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but presumably get returns an array, so I guess you could just implode/flatten the array